# Calling custom designed UIAlertView inside custom designed UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I'm struggling against this problem for days.

I have a custom designed UIAlertView (A new UIAlertView inherited class whose name is ProductAlertView) and I want to open a new custom designed UIAlertView (that is also a UIAlertView inherited class). When I create this new custom designed UIAlertView inside the custom designed alertview,  new designed alertview isn't seen well (some images lost...) 
Also, I tried to implement a singleton class which closes the first alertview then opens the second alertview; however, it didn't change that the view isn't seen fully and well again.

Does anyone have solution for that?

Some code:

First AlertView

```
#import "ProductAlertView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "MessageAlertView.h"
#import "Communicator.h"
#import "MainGameScene.h"
#import "UpdateMe.h"

@implementation ProductAlertView
@synthesize image;
@synthesize unitId;
@synthesize player_id;
@synthesize location_id;
@synthesize unitName;
@synthesize currentLevel;
@synthesize tab1Name;
@synthesize alertName;
@synthesize imageTab1;
@synthesize buttonTab1;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize productArray;
@synthesize seller_id;

//int MAXLEVEL = 5;


-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGSize size = self.image.size;
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
}



- (void) show {
    // Test the labels


    // call the super show method to initiate the animation
    [super show];

    // resize the alert view to fit the image
    CGSize imageSize = self.image.size;
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);



    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 40, 440, 180)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.20]];
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    //scrollView.alpha = 1.0;
    int i;
    int j = 2;
    for (i = 0; i < [productArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *unitDict = [productArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bina_s_1.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 107, 154)];
        imageView.image = image2;

        UILabel *moneyLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 80, 40, 20)];
        NSString *moneyStr = [[unitDict objectForKey:@"buyPrice"] description];
        [moneyLbl setText:moneyStr];
        [moneyLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Comic Sans MS" size:15]];
        [moneyLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.0]];

        UILabel *minLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 100, 40, 20)];
        NSString *durationStr = [[unitDict objectForKey:@"name"] description];
        [minLbl setText:durationStr];
        [minLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Comic Sans MS" size:15]];
        [minLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.0]];

        UILabel *dpLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 120, 40, 20)];
        NSString *xpStr = [[unitDict objectForKey:@"xp"] description];
        [dpLbl setText:xpStr];
        [dpLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Comic Sans MS" size:15]];
        [dpLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.0]];

        [imageView addSubview:moneyLbl];
        [imageView addSubview:minLbl];
        [imageView addSubview:dpLbl];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(j, 5, 107, 154);
        button.tag = i;
        [button addSubview:imageView];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
        j += 110;
    }

    UILabel *tab1Lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 7, 70, 20)];
    [tab1Lbl setText:tab1Name];
    [tab1Lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ComicSansMS" size:15]];
    [tab1Lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.0]];

    UILabel *alertLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(340, 5, 85, 20)];
    [alertLbl setText:alertName];
    [alertLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ComicSansMS" size:15]];
    [alertLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.59 blue:0.062 alpha:0.0]];

    UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"exit1.png"];
    UIButton *buttonExit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonExit.frame = CGRectMake(425, 5, 21, 20);
    [buttonExit setImage:image4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonExit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    imageTab1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"panel_btn_active.png"];
    buttonTab1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonTab1.frame = CGRectMake(3, 7, 93, 20);
    [buttonTab1 setImage:imageTab1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    CGSize size1;
    size1.width = 550;
    size1.height = 75;
    [scrollView setContentSize:size1];


    [self addSubview:buttonTab1];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [self addSubview:tab1Lbl];
    [self addSubview:alertLbl];
    [self addSubview:buttonExit];
}
- (void) clickType:(id) sender{

    int myTag = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"Sender Tag:%i",myTag);
    //[self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    /*
     MessageAlertView *alertView = [[MessageAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
     [alertView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tebrikler_panel.png"]];

     [alertView show];
     */
    NSString *str;
    NSDictionary *collectibleDict = [productArray objectAtIndex:myTag];

    Communicator *comm = [[Communicator alloc] init];
    [comm buyAndSellCollectible:[location_id intValue] withBuyerId:[player_id intValue] withSellerId:[seller_id intValue] withCollectibleId:[[collectibleDict objectForKey:@"collectible_id"] intValue]];
    NSString *respStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[comm getRespStr] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"%@",respStr);
    NSDictionary *dict = [respStr JSONValue];

    NSString *header;

    if (![[dict objectForKey:@"msgtype"] isEqualToString:@"error"]) {
        header = [NSString stringWithString:@"Helallll!"];
        [UpdateMe checkLevel:[player_id intValue]];
        [UpdateMe checkMoneyXP:[player_id intValue]];
        [UpdateMe checkBagStatus:[player_id intValue]];
    }
    else{
        header = [NSString stringWithString:@"Errorrrr!"];
    }

    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"msg"]];

    [[MainGameScene sharedMySingleton] showMessageAlertView:@"Hello" withMessage2:@"Hello 2" closeAlertView:self];
}
- (void) exitAlert{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
- (void) dealloc{
    [unitId release];
    [player_id release];
    [location_id release];
    [seller_id release];
    [unitName release];
    [currentLevel release];
    [productArray release];
    [tab1Name release];
    [alertName release];
    [imageTab1 release];
    [buttonTab1 release];
    [scrollView release];
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Second AlertView

```
#import "MessageAlertView.h"


@implementation MessageAlertView

@synthesize image;
@synthesize message1;
@synthesize message2;


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGSize size = self.image.size;
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
}

- (void) show{

    [super show];
    CGSize imageSize = self.image.size;
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

    UILabel *lblMessage1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 1, 70, 30)];
    [lblMessage1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.5 alpha:0]];
    [lblMessage1 setText:message1];

    UILabel *lblMessage2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 60, 200, 30)];
    [lblMessage2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.5 alpha:0]];
    [lblMessage2 setText:message2];

    UIButton *okButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [okButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.3 alpha:0]];
    okButton.frame = CGRectMake(133, 103, 80, 25);
    okButton.alpha = 0.1;
    [okButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

    UIImage *imageClose = [UIImage imageNamed:@"exit1.png"];
    UIButton *buttonClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonClose.frame = CGRectMake(320, 4, 21, 20);
    [buttonClose setImage:imageClose forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonClose addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

    [self addSubview:okButton];
    [self addSubview:lblMessage1];
    [self addSubview:lblMessage2];
    [self addSubview:buttonClose];
}

- (void) closeView{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [message1 release];
    [message2 release];
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

in MainGameScene class i opened second AlertView like that:

```
-(void) showMessageAlertView:(NSString *)message1 withMessage2:(NSString *)message2 closeAlertView:(UIAlertView *)closeAlertView{
    [closeAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    MessageAlertView *alertView = [[MessageAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    [alertView setMessage1:message1];
    [alertView setMessage2:message2];
    [alertView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tebrikler_panel.png"]];

    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: without some code is very difficult to guess something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't a chance to create a similar scenario to confirm, but I suggest you try to open `MessageAlertView` outside `ProductAlertView`. You can achieve this by making `MainGameScene` respond to [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) protocol:

```
@interface MainGameScene : ParentClass <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    // ...
}
```

and set delegate of `ProductAlertView` before showing it by `MainGameScene`:

```
ProductAlertView *alertView = ...
// whatever need to be set
[alertView setDelegate:self];
[alertView show];
```

and implement this method in `MainGameScene`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    MessageAlertView *alertView = [[MessageAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    [alertView setMessage1:@"Hello"];
    [alertView setMessage2:@"Hello2"];
    [alertView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tebrikler_panel.png"]];

    [alertView show];
}
```

As a result, the first alert view will be dismissed first, and then the second will be shown.